# Alert from a java file before redirect

Tags: javascript, java

I have a form on my JSP page which goes to a Java file upon submit. After performing certain steps, this Java file redirects to another JSP page.

Prior to redirecting, I want to display an alert on whether the form submission was successful or not. In other JSP pages, I used javascript alert() function to perform this. I can't do that as this is a java file.

I tried to use JOptionPane but the alert box doesn't appear on the broswer page, it appears on my desktop (Is that weird or supposed to be normal..). I tried with println and it ends up only printing out to console.

So is there anyway I can call a Javascript alert inside a .java file or other way to show an alert? Everything in the java file works less the alert.

Java File

```
private void alert(String msg){

        //this doesn't print to console, doesn't show alert
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        out.println("alert(" + msg + ");");
        out.println("</script>");

        //This prints to console only
        /*System.out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        System.out.println("alert(" + msg + ");");
        System.out.println("</script>");*/
    }

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // gets values of text fields
        String name = request.getParameter("name");

        InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
        Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
        if (filePart != null) {
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }

        Connection conn = null; // connection to the database

        try {
            // connects to the database
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

            // constructs SQL statement
            String sql = "INSERT INTO table(name, image) values (?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, name);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                statement.setBlob(2, inputStream);
            }

            // sends the statement to the database server
            int row = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (row > 0) {
                //This ends up appearing on my desktop instead of inside the browser.
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input successful");

                //**THIS is the alert that doesn't show up** 
                alert("Input successful");

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the HTML inside of you servlet it really something to avoid.  I personally would either make this into an AJAX call or, at the very least, redirect first to a "success.jsp" (or something like it) and, from there redirect to "home.jsp".  That isn't the best user experience but your design is rather challenging.

Comment: Not sure about Ajax call in this instance. I get your redirecting idea. Guess I'll keep that as my worse case back plan if I don't find any other alternative :).